# $2x^2+2xy-x+y=112$. Find natural solutions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've got this and I'm stuck:

$(x-2)(x-y)=11-y$. Is it possible to make something out of this?

Oops, I've got that on the other problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$y=1-x+\frac{111}{2x+1}$$

Comment: oh yeah now just to find all x that 2x+1 divides 111 is left and y is calculated.

Comment: ie $(2x+1)(x+y-1)=111$ so the instinct to find a factorisation is correct, it is necessary though to pick up all the terms in $x$ and $y$ to make this work easily.